# Why do I need to call fit() before transform() when using PolynomialFeatures?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Hello to all you great minds,

I'm trying to understand more rigorously the way polynomial fitting works with scikit. More specifically, what I'm trying to do is break down the process, and to only show a dataframe with the new polynomial features generated based on a single value.

So I have data which with several entries, each is 1-dimensional. I want to generate a design matrix suitable for polynomial fitting. What I am currently doing is along these lines:

```
pd.DataFrame(PolynomialFeatures(k).fit_transform(X))
```

And this works as expected.

However, what I'm struggling with is the role of fit_transform(). As far as I am concerned, and I not trying to *fit* anything quiet yet, merely produce a dataframe with the newly constructed polynomial features. Naively I tried changing fit_transform() to transform(), but apparently I have to use fit before I am allowed to transform.

I would appreciate it if anyone could point me to my error. I am not yet trying to fit a model on the data, only to create a design matrix with the polynomial features, so why do I have to use fit() (or fit_transform(), to that matter)? In fact, I don't really understand what fit() actually does here, and the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html#sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.fit) didn't help me wrap my head around it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for this is to be consistent with their API. When doing preprocessing you still want to "fit" to some train data and apply the same preprocessing step to the train AND the test data.
An example where it becomes more clear is Standardscaling (which is a different preprocessing step). You calculate the mean and std from the train data and apply the same scaling (X - mean) / std to the train AND test data (with the mean and std taken from the train data.
Therefore the two methods `fit` and `transform` are separated.

In your case of polynomial features it probably makes no sense to "fit", because no information is extracted from the train data and the step can directly be applied to the test data without knowing the train data. But including the `fit` in `PolynomialFeatures` makes it consistent with their whole API. The consistency  becomes necessary when you pipe multiple preprocessing steps.